# Why Quantile Regression Forest grows trees in standard way (i.e. using MSE to decide splits)?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, quantiles, quantile-regression

I'm interested in training a Random Forrest model to predict conditional quantiles (e.g., P75, P90) given the features instead of the conditional mean. [Sklearn's RandomForestRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) has a mean absolute error (MAE) loss which build trees by using the median of each the terminal nodes, thus minimizing MAE - naturally, the resulting model is a P50 model.

If now I want a P75 model it makes sense to use the quantile loss with q=0.75 and grow the trees by predicting the empirical P75 (aka Q3). However, this is not implemented in sklearn.

The best solution I've found is [Quantile Regression Forests](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Enicolai/quantregforests.pdf). Here authors build trees "normally" which I assume is with regular MSE loss and store the targets of all terminal nodes of all trees and use these to output the predicted quantile.

My questions are, why would this work if trees are built "normally"? which means the individual trees are grown to optimize MSE, not quantiles. By growing the tree with the desired quantile (as described previously) wouldn't we get better splits?

Thanks!